# the layout not show in react-native app ? how solve it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

i am new to react native and create project with expo
my layout is not showing
how solve it?

i created a app folder and add layout

```
-   app.json
-   babel.config.js
-   index.js
-   package-lock.json
-   package.json
----app
-       index.js
-       _layout.js 
----node_modules
-   *
```

index.js in root:

```
import "expo-router/entry";
import  Home  from "./app/index";

export default Home;
```

index.js in app

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
const Home = () => {
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Home Page</Text>
    </View>
}
export default Home;
```

layout.js

```
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';

const Layout = (props) => {
    return <Stack />
}
export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home is not returning anything. You either need to use an `implicit` or `explicit` return.

`Implicit` return.

```js
const Home = () => (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Home Page</Text>
    </View>
)
```

`Explicit` return.

```js
const Home = () => {
    return (<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Home Page</Text>
    </View>)
}
```

Take a note of the use of parenthesis in the first example, and the curly braces in the second.